# "FV" abbreviation in BrewDog recipe

Tags: hops, dry-hop

I am attempting to follow a recipe in BrewDog's excellent [DIY DOG](https://6303ffd34a16b1ca5276-a9447b7dfa4ae38e337b359963d557c4.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/DIY%20DOG.pdf)
(see Albino Squid Assassin recipe, page 217)

As hop additions, as the last 2 additions it lists:

```
* Chinook 100g   FV   Aroma
* Citra 75g      FV   Aroma
```

Throughout the other recipes it tends to list the last set of hops as "Dry Hop". (in fact the recipe on the previous page lists hops for both "Dry Hop" and "FV")

What does FV mean here? Add to the fermentation vessel, while fermentation is still occurring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently it means to add to Fermentation Vessel as you noted.

https://www.brewdog.com/lowdown/blog/diy-dog

I'm guessing it means in the primary, as most dry hops are in secondary.

This would be the similar as a whirlpool addition, but have more rest time and hop trub for the primary.

**Edit** After more review of the other recipes. FV would be in the primary, after fermentation is well underway but not complete. Many of the "FV" additions would benifiet from the early alcohol for sanitation and churning of the wort during primary for suspension.

So this "FV" addition method is relatively unique, from other addition methods.

Comment: Ah, good spot! _"'FV' means fermentation vessel, so any ingredient stated as FV means it is added post-fermentation to take on the flavours (oak chips, fruit etc) at that final stage of the process"._

So, wait for fermentation to finish, then add hops into primary and leave for another week?

Comment: @RYFN I think this a pre fermentation addition. As some of the other recipes specify some ingredients to be added "to FV post fermentation"

Comment: Great, do you think I should leave the wort for a couple of days to get started, or chuck the hops in shortly after the yeast has been mixed in and aerated?

Comment: @RYFN looks like at high krausen or shortly after is what is intended by FV. To benifiet from tincture effect and sanitation from alcohol and churning of wort from violent fermentation for suspension or the addition.

Answer (score 0):

a local brewery made a new england pale ale and posted the recipe online.
OG: 1.057,
FG: 1.011

and they added hops in three occasions:
-SG: 1.018,
-SG: 1.011,
-three days after it reached 1.011.

So I think FV should right after the violent fermentation (usually when you switch from the hose to the airlock)